# How to gain control on window based application in java

Tags: java

How can i gain control on window based appliaction in java.
I am not asking like world or Excel.
I am asking for a window based application, suppose a media player(not specific window media player) any media player that is running on window.

Comment: Are you asking of programatical control in other words good grip or you are asking about native control through app ?

Comment: I am asking for native control.
Suppose that i set a command to my java application that at particular time media player will run and it play a song that is stored in a particular path.

Comment: You can execute shell command from java and maintain timertask for scheduling check   

`   String command = "wmplayer.exe";
    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);`

Answer (score 1):

How would you control the windows based application if you took Java out of the equation?

- Does the program provide a COM interface? There are a number of Java-COM
  bridges.
- Does the program provide a plug-in API? You could write the DLL in C/C++, then either use JNI/JNA to interact with the DLL from Java, or use some kind-of interprocess communications layer.
- Do you have have some view in the to low level Win32 message pump of the program?  Then perhaps you could create native DLL to send messages via SendMessage on behalf of the java program.

It really depends on what you expect to do with the program, and what the program provides.  There is no built-in functionality allowing one program to control another program, especially from Java.

Comment: Application does not provide the COM interface.

can you simple tell me how to use JNI so that i can install application through this.
Or there is much better approach then JNI.